# Reshaping a pandas pivoted dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pivoted dataframe:

```
variable           A         B         C         D
date                                              
2000-01-03  0.469112 -1.135632  0.119209 -2.104569
2000-01-04 -0.282863  1.212112 -1.044236 -0.494929
2000-01-05 -1.509059 -0.173215 -0.861849  1.071804
```

How can I convert it to a new dataframe of the following format:

```
date           A         B         C         D
2000-01-03  0.469112 -1.135632  0.119209 -2.104569
2000-01-04 -0.282863  1.212112 -1.044236 -0.494929
2000-01-05 -1.509059 -0.173215 -0.861849  1.071804
```

where "date" is not an index in the second dataframe. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I've read [Trouble pivoting / reshaping a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21837084/trouble-pivoting-reshaping-a-pandas-dataframe) but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reset the index

`df.reset_index()`