# How to transpose part of a dataframe in Jupyter notebooks?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, slice, transpose

I have a large dataset that is organized as such:

| Region | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| New York | Nov 2019 | 3 |
| New York | Nov 2020 | 4 |
| New York | Nov 2021 | 6 |
| Seattle | Nov 2019 | 1 |
| Seattle | Nov 2020 | 2 |
| Seattle | Nov 2021 | 4 |

And I want a transposed output that looks like this:

| Region | Nov 2019 | Nov 2020 | Nov 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| New York | 3 | 4 | 6 |
| Seattle | 1 | 2 | 4 |

The dataset has 20,000+ rows encompassing more than a thousand cities, so I need an easy way to slice the dataset to retain the city column but transpose the rest. It seems like a simple solution but I'm at a loss. Thanks!

Just running df.transpose() leads to the city names being spread out as columns as well, which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transposing part of a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21837084/transposing-part-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Could you share the code you’ve tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html)** or **[`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)**:

```
dfx = pd.crosstab(df['Region'], df['Date'],df['Value'],aggfunc='first')
```

or

```
dfx_v2 = df.pivot_table(values='Value',index='Region',columns='Date')
```

**Output**:

```
Date      Nov 2019     Nov 2020    Nov 2021
Region                                
New York         3         4         6
Seattle          1         2         4
```